# Replacement for HAXM on ubuntu - says Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator is not compatible

Tags: android-studio, android-sdk

I'm using `Android Studio` and I need to add ***Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator*** to it's not compatible with Linux. Is there any software I could use instead and how would I install it onto Android Studio?

Answer (score 7):

Check if your CPU supports hardware virtualization,  by typing:

```
egrep -c '(vmx|svm)' /proc/cpuinfo
```

If the result is 0, your CPU does not support hardware virtualization, which is necessary to run the KVM. If you get 1 or more, that means you’re fine.

Next, install KVM. First make sure if your processor supports KVM by typing:

```
kvm-ok
```

You will see this if that’s the case:

> INFO: Your CPU supports KVM extensions INFO: /dev/kvm exists KVM
>   acceleration can be used

If this is the result, you need to turn on `Intel VT` in **BIOS**:

> INFO: KVM is disabled by your BIOS HINT: Enter your BIOS setup and
>   enable Virtualization Technology (VT), and then hard poweroff/poweron
>   your system KVM acceleration can NOT be used

The next step is to install the KVM and a few other packages needed. To do so, type:

```
sudo apt-get install qemu-kvm libvirt-bin ubuntu-vm-builder bridge-utils
```

Add your user to some groups, replacing  by your own username:

```
sudo adduser <user> libvirtd
sudo adduser <user> kvm
```

Check if everything is ok:

```
sudo virsh -c qemu:///system list
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34590506/4409113).

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: After following your steps when I launch android to manage SDK and I checkbox ON the `Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer)` it ignores my request and does not install ... ?

Comment: @ScottStensland I think SDK manager doesn't have the (root)privilage(maybe) to install, Same in windows, When i don't give administrator access, It won't install it...Check this point and let me know.

Comment: One more thing, In windows, When user checkbox on this installer, It will download the packages, *But it doesn't install it*. I think in your situation, You'll need to find it and then install it manually, As well as we do this on windows...The path in windows is : `C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\extras\intel` maybe this can help to install it manually...

Comment: After reading doc at https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2012/03/12/how-to-start-intel-hardware-assisted-virtualization-hypervisor-on-linux-to-speed-up-intel-android-x86-emulator   on a 64 bit ubuntu 16.04 I issued suggested set of cmds shown above in your answer  then   I was able to launch HAXM accelerator using syntax   /path/android-sdk-linux/tools/emulator64-x86 -avd   <myavdname>  -qemu -m 2047 -enable-kvm

Comment: In above solution, libvirt-bin is obsoleted, and instead of it use libvirt-daemon-system.